# after a splash screen maximized window won't show any elements

Tags: c#, wpf, splash-screen

I have created a splash screen and after the animation, I am closing the splash and showing the login form that is maximized. The login form is blank,it isn't showing any elements until I minimized it. If I run the app from visual studio, it works fine, when I run it from the debug .exe file,it doesn't. If the login screen isn't set to maximized, it shows fine. 
This is my splash screen:

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="Manager.Splash"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Manager"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Splash" Height="350" Width="525" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize" ShowInTaskbar="False" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard Name="storyBoard">
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:03" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0">
                </DoubleAnimation>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
<Grid>
    <Image Name="splash" Source="/Slike/Splash.png"></Image>
</Grid>
```

code behind

```
 public partial class Splash : Window
{
    public Splash()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        load();
    }

    private void load()
    {
        storyBoard.Completed += new EventHandler(Story_Completed);
    }

    private void Story_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Start appStart = new Start();
        this.Close();
        appStart.ShowDialog();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the code behind.

For some reason

```
appStart.ShowDialog()
```

was the problem.

```
asppStart.Show();
```

solved the problem,although I don't know why